# How to burn HD videos with menu system onto DVD media?

Tags: video, dvd, blu-ray, high-definition, authoring

I'll be getting a HD editing rig soon at my studio where we make mostly corporate AVs. So far our format is PAL SD and usually the delivered product is a MPEG or AVI as the client demands. Occasionally, some projects are delivered as authored Video DVDS.

With the new setup, we'll look to output 720p either as MPEG-4 part 2 or part 10 (H.264) in suitable containers like AVI/MOV/MKV/MP4. So standalone videos are fine for data DVDs. But what about the equivalent for a menu-driven environment like in a Video DVD. Almost certainly, most of the end users will not have access to Blu-Ray players. So, **is there any way to create DVDs containing a menu-driven environment but with HD videos**? Third party self-contained frameworks are welcome, depending on the economics. Hopefully, any solution will enjoy similar levels of compatibility as Video DVDs.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm aware of the allowed formats in the DVD-Video spec. In case it isn't clear, I want to emulate a similar structure containing HD video objects, but to be burnt onto DVD. As long as the peak bitrate is below, say, 8mbps, the DVD should be a workable playback host for 720p video.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do can put HD content in DVD, as the DVD standard only allow MPEG1 or MPEG2, so it is impossible to use MPEG4 on DVD to start with. Secondly, you wanted output to be 720p. But the DVD standard only allow 720 × 576 @ 25fps or 720 × 480 @30 fps. Because of these limitation on DVD that's why we come up with bluray/hddvd standard.